# Android parsing an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following ArrayList

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
HashMap<String, String> map;
```

with the following values inside:

```
list[0] = map.put("key_0", value_0);
list[1] = map.put("key_1", value_1);
list[2] = map.put("key_2", value_2);
```

I would like to parse the `list` array and get the value of the key at a specific position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the particular map from the ArrayList> by using `get()` method. for example,

```
map = list.get(index);
```

And to get key of that map, you can do:

```
String key = map.get("key");
```

FYI, this is the feasible solution, i dont know why you are using key name like key_0, key_1, key_2...and so on.

Comment: You're right. The `key_names` are all the same for each `list` item. Initially I meant writing it this way: `list[0] = map("key_0", value_0, "key_1", value_1 etc.  )`